# Chrome: Selected element does not receive "copy" event

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, copy-paste, dom-events

When setting focus to the first `div` in the following example and using CTRL+C to copy, why does the second div receive the event?

```js
const selectAreas = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("select-area"));
selectAreas.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  const windowSelection = window.getSelection();
  windowSelection.removeAllRanges();
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(element);
  windowSelection.addRange(range);
}))

selectAreas.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  console.log("Copy! Area: " + element.id);
}))
```

```html
<div class="select-area" id="area1" style="user-select: none" tabindex="0">
  I am text
</div>

<div class="select-area" id="area2" tabindex="0">
  I am text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the first element is set `user-select: none`. From the documentation:

> The text of the element and its sub-elements is not selectable. Note
>   that the Selection object can contain these elements.

However, this element has been explicitly added to the Selection so it *should* receive the `copy` event. The browser, seeing that this element is not selectable, finds the nearest element that is selectable and sends the event there.

---

Obviously, the fix for this contrived example is to remove `user-select: none`.